# C# Partial binary deserialization of class with lists

Tags: c#, list, class, serialization, binary

Friendly greetings! 

I've started working with binary serialization for saving / loading data because of the speed of this method.
I've created a little class for training purposes and it works perfectly!

```
[Serializable()]
    public class School : ISerializable
    {
        internal List<int> Boards, Tables, Children;
        public School()
        {
            this.Boards = new List<int>();
            this.Tables = new List<int>();
            this.Children = new List<int>();
        }
        public School(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
        {
            this.Boards = (List<int>)info.GetValue("Boards", typeof(List<int>));
            this.Tables = (List<int>)info.GetValue("Tables", typeof(List<int>));
            this.Children = (List<int>)info.GetValue("Children", typeof(List<int>));
        }
        public void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
        {
            info.AddValue("Boards", Boards);
            info.AddValue("Tables", Tables);
            info.AddValue("Children", Children);
        }
        public void FillRandom()
        {
            for (int a = 0; a < 1000; a++)
                this.Boards.Add(a);
            for (int b = 0; b < 1000; b++)
                this.Tables.Add(b);
            for (int c = 0; c < 1000; c++)
                this.Children.Add(c);
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Saves the current state of this class to a serialized data file.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="path">File location</param>
        public void Serialize(string path)
        {
            using (FileStream FS = File.Open(path, FileMode.Create))
            {
                BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
                bf.Serialize(FS, this);
                FS.Close();
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Deserializes the data file and builds a School class from the retrieved information.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="path">File location</param>
        /// <returns>Filled People class</returns>
        public static People Deserialize(string path)
        {
            using (FileStream FS = File.Open(path, FileMode.Open))
            {
                BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
                People p = (People)bf.Deserialize(FS);
                FS.Close();
                return p;
            }
        }
    }
```

I'm sorry for the loads of code.

**Here's my question**
I need to retrieve a part of a List due to the large size of the lists that may be stored in this file. It's mainly a memory-use precaution to prevent it filling up when multiple users are accessing the server...
I couldnt figure out how to approach this and i'd appreciate help from someone with more expertise in this subject.


Thanks for your time!

Comment: You want to load only one of the lists from the file?

Comment: I want to load a specific index of a list in the file.

Comment: To my limited knowledge, you have two possibilities: Partitioning (where you commit small chunks of objects together - say, 100 blocks of 100 objects instead of 10k serialized objects together) or parsing (where you read from the storage - caveat being that you'll need to abandon the binary format and use a parser (eg. XML or JSON) instead).

Comment: @Raybbo there is no array indexes in the file. You can only move current position for certain bytes. If you know how much byte is taken by one Board, you can skip file header and (N-1)*sizeof(Board). However I would like to suggest use some embedded SQL server or db (dbx) file from Paradox database. At least you will get high level abstraction instead of seeking by file with binary serialized object